# aws datapipeline s3 to mysql error

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-data-pipeline

I am trying to load around 40gb file (split across 520 parts each around 90MB) located on S3 into mysql. I created aws data pipeline S3 to MySQL.

Before loading I processed these records in Hive and then stored output files on S3. some records in file contain \N to represent NULL value. When I try to load such records data, pipeline fails. But same can be loaded with SQOOP as it can handle NULL values while loading into MYSQL.

Does anyone have an idea whether I can load such records in MySQL from S3 using data pipeline? Is there any JDBC property that I can set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this can be done very easily by changing the connection string to below syntax. You have to set `jdbcCompliantTruncation` to false.

```
jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
```

So your connection string will look some thing like below.

> jdbc:mysql://my-rds-endpoint:3306/my_db_name?jdbcCompliantTruncation=false

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. My column is BIGINT type would it impact after adding jdbcCompliantTruncation=false?

Comment: No it will not as you are just setting the flag to false.